# (read-command ...) returns strange object upon blank input

Tags: emacs, elisp, string-interning

I need to prompt the user for a command, using `read-command`, then take an action based on whether or not the user entered the empty string on the minibuffer.

Most of the time, `read-command` returns a valid command. But when the user enters a blank string (by just hitting enter in the minibuffer), a strange object is returned, which is neither `nil`, nor a string, nor a command (according to `stringp` and `commandp`).

```
ELISP> (setq strange-object (read-command "Enter some command" nil) )
ELISP> (equal nil strange-object)
nil
ELISP> (if strange-object "YES" "NO")
"YES"
ELISP> (mapcar (lambda (fun) (funcall fun strange-object)) (list 'stringp 'commandp 'char-or-string-p 'functionp 'integerp 'listp) )
(nil nil nil nil nil nil)
ELISP> (prin1-to-string strange-object)
""
ELISP> (equal "" strange-object)
nil
```

How can I:

1. Access the read-syntax of this object?
2. Determine the type of the object without matching against every type predicate defined [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Type-Predicates.html#Type-Predicates)
3. Test for equality against this object?
4. Why is `read-command` misbehaving? Specification of `read-command`:

> read-command is a built-in function in `minibuf.c'.
>
> (read-command PROMPT &optional DEFAULT-VALUE)
>
> Read the name of a command and return as a symbol. Prompt with PROMPT.
>   By default, return DEFAULT-VALUE or its first element if it is a list.
>
> [back]

I expected `nil`, since that is what I passed as `DEFAULT-VALUE`, but apparently `read-command` doesn't care.

I've tried loading the source of `minibuf.c` to see what is going on, but I haven't been able to get that to work either. I've downloaded `emacs-23.3b.tar.gz` from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/) and had emacs look for the source there, but it wasn't able to find it. Neither does a `minibuf.c` seem to exist there. Very frustrating stuff, I will appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elisp manual is your friend. `C-h i`, choose Elisp. Then `i` and enter `read-command`. As part of the description you see this:

```
 The argument DEFAULT specifies what to return if the user enters
 null input.  It can be a symbol, a string or a list of strings.
 If it is a string, `read-command' interns it before returning it.
 If it is a list, `read-command' interns the first element of this
 list.  If DEFAULT is `nil', that means no default has been
 specified; then if the user enters null input, the return value is
 `(intern "")', that is, a symbol whose name is an empty string.
```

Read the full description.  But this alone should help you understand.  The value returned is a ***symbol*** that has an empty name.

Comment: (equal (intern "") strange-object) ==> t.

I have no idea why this isn't part of the normal `read-command` documentation, why this important information is hidden in some obscure manual. So much frustration that could have been avoided. 

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Any hints as to how to find the sources for these c functions?

Comment: Ok, I had to point to the `src` directory rather than the top one. I am sure I had done this before. It'd still be helpful to know whether it is possible to get the read syntax for an arbitrary object, but again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I agree that in this case the doc string could say a little more, especially since the code is not in Lisp. If you feel strongly about it, consider filing a bug/enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I had never noticed that we return this funny "empty symbol" in this case.  It looks like a misfeature to me: this empty symbol is a bit unusual to work with (in Emacs trunk, we have made it properly print+readable, but still).

Comment: @Stefan: Agreed. And in this case, I don't expect there would be much breakage if this behavior were changed. I doubt that a lot of code uses `read-command` anyway, and I don't imagine that much of any such code makes use of this "feature", i.e., this return value.